# How to interpret a function signature

Tags: f#

**I am still confused on how to read function signatures.**

The Option.map signature is the following:

```
/// map f inp evaluates to match inp with None -> None | Some x -> Some (f x).
/// mapping: A function to apply to the option value.
/// option: The input option.
val map : mapping:('T -> 'U) -> option:'T option -> 'U option
```

However, I have no clue what that signature means.

**I read it as the following:**

There's a function called **map** that takes a function as an input that we'll call **"mapping"** and it will yield a result that is also a function that we'll call **"option"**.

**Mapping Parameter:**

```
mapping:('T -> 'U)
```

The function that we pass in as input takes **Titanium** (i.e. 'T) as the input and yields **Uranium** (i.e. 'U) as output.

**The Option returned**

```
option:'T option -> 'U option
```

We'll call the output of the map function **"option"**.
Thus, this **"option"** that is returned from executing the **map** function **is also a function** as referenced above. It's takes a **Titanium option** and yields a **Uranium option**.

**Example:**

```
type String20 = String20 of string

type Name = { First:String20
              Last:String20
              Suffix:String20 option }

let tryCreateName (first:string) (last:string) (suffix:string option) = 

    let isValid = [first; last] 
                  |> List.forall (fun x -> x.Length > 2 && x.Length <= 20)

    if isValid then 
        Some { First  = String20(first); 
               Last   = String20(last); 
               Suffix = Option.map String20 suffix }
    else None
```

**How does the following expression map:**

```
Option.map String20 suffix
```

Based on the expression above, where is the "returned function" of **Titanium option** -> **Uranium option**?

Comment: I was wondering when you would ask this question.

Comment: Return values don't have names, so the `map` function has two parameters - `mapping: ('T -> 'U)` and `option: 'T option`.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought "->" meant yield. Hence, it is in-between the two parameters.

Comment: Your questions are great for beginners. Please keep asking more to help the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off take a look at [Option.map<'T,'U> Function (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340461.aspx) and notice

> The expression map f inp evaluates to match inp with None -> None |
>   Some x -> Some (f x).

So lets convert this comment to working code. First map is a method of the type Option, but to make it easier we will make it a function outside of a type and to avoid conflicts with other map functions we will give it the name OptionMap.

```
let OptionMap = f inp =
    match inp with
    | None -> None
    | Some x -> Some (f x)
```

Now to get the signature of this function just send it to F# Interactive

```
val OptionMap : f:('a -> 'b) -> inp:'a option -> 'b option
```

and to make the types obvious we will type the parameters of the function.

```
let optionMap (f : ('a -> 'b)) (inp : 'a option) : 'b option =
    match inp with
    | None -> None
    | Some x -> Some (f x)
```

Now to test this we can use

```
let (test : String20 option) = optionMap String20 (Some("something"))
printfn "test: %A" test
// test: Some (String20 "something")
```

So what happened in OptionMap that allowed this to work

If we add some print statements let sees what happens

```
let optionMap (f : ('a -> 'b)) (inp : 'a option) : 'b option =
    printfn "f:   %A" f
    printfn "inp: %A" inp
    match inp with
    | None -> None
    | Some x -> 
            let result = Some (f x)
    printfn "result: %A" result
    result
```

we get

```
f:   <fun:test@63>
inp: Some "something"
result: Some (String20 "something")
```

we see that f is a function which is String20

So how can String20 be a function?

If we send String20 to F# Interactive it gives.

```
> String20;;
val it : arg0:string -> String20 = <fun:clo@4>
```

So String20 is a function that takes a string and returns a type of String20. That smells of a constructor.

Let's test that out in F# interactive.

```
> let test1 = String20 "something";;

val test1 : String20 = String20 "something"
```

Sure enough, String20 is a constructor, but we didn't specifically create a constructor as is done in the Object-Oriented world.

You have to think of a type, even a discriminated union as having constructors. The constructors are not specifically written but do exist. So String20 is a constructor that takes one value, a string, which is a function with the correct type signature for the Option.map function.

I gave the answer a lot more detail so that one can learn a process on how to break down problems and look at the inner workings as a tool to solving these kinds of problems.

To learn more about the lower level details of how functional programming works one needs to understand [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). The best way I know to learn it is to read [An Introduction To Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/library/functional_programming/gjm.lambook88.pdf) by Greg Michaelson and look at the info in the [lambda calculus tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lambda-calculus/info).

Also if you like the book, you should buy a copy instead of using the free version.

Comment: Thanks Guy Coder. I got hung-up on "->" operator. I thought that it always meant yield. I didn't know that it's also an argument separator within a function signature.

Comment: I too had similar problems. It is only when I took the time to learn all of the basics did it become clearer faster. Since functional programming is like math and when the math teacher would write the sequence of transformations on the board and skip a few lines it was very confusing. When the skipped lines were added did it make more sense. Spend more time on the basics and it will pay off. I myself did [thousands of basic test](https://github.com/jack-pappas/fsharp-logic-examples/blob/master/FSharpx.Books.AutomatedReasoning.Tests/lib.fs) on basic functions and it really paid off.

Comment: Just bought Greg Michaelson's book on Kindle

Comment: It will take some time to read and pays off if you practice the examples. I spent about six months in detail with it and don't know how well I would be doing if I did not use it. It specifically focuses on lambda calculus first with untyped lambda calculus then onto typed lambda calculus so don't expect it to teach you F# which is functional and object oriented combined. If you get stuck on it, ask questions here as the community will benefit from it.

Comment: Also take a look at the references in [Learning F#: What books using other programming languages can be translated to F# to learn functional concepts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662896/learning-f-what-books-using-other-programming-languages-can-be-translated-to-f)

Comment: @ScottNimrod: yes, the arrow `->` _does_ always mean "yield". There is no such concept as "parameter separator".

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of looking at it.

```
let f x y = x + y
// val f: x:int -> y:int -> int
```

One way is to say that function `f` takes two parameters, `x` of type `int` and `y` of type `int`, and returns an `int`. So I can supply two arguments and get the result:

```
let a = f 4 5
// val a: int = 9
```

The other way is that the function takes one parameter, `x` of type `int`, and returns another function, which takes one parameter, `y` of type `int`, and returns an `int`. So I can supply one argument and get a function as result:

```
let b = f 4
// val b: int -> int
```

Mathematically, it's always the second way - all functions are one-parameter functions. This notion is very convenient for programming with higher-order functions.
But the first way is usually more understandable to humans, so you will often see functions discussed as if they take multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you have a function `T1 -> T2 -> ...` and you apply it to one parameter, you get a function `T2 -> ...`. In the case of `Option.map`, `T1` is itself a function, but that is of no consequence to the way the arguments are applied.

*I find it confusing to call a function "option", a string "Titanium" and a type called String20 "Uranium", so I'll stick with type names.*

You ask where the "returned function" that maps a string option to a String20 option is in the expression `Option.map String20 suffix`. It is simply

```
Option.map String20
```

Since `String20` constructs a String20 from a string, `Option.map String20` is a function that maps a string to a String20 if it is present, and to None otherwise.

If you write `Option.map String20 suffix`, this function is applied to `suffix`, which would be a string option. The result of this expression is a String20 option.

Answer (score 2):

`String20` is the *case constructor* for the `String20` Discriminated Union case. It's a *function* with the type `string -> String20`. So `string` takes the place of `'T`, and `String20` takes the place of `'U` in the `mapping` you supply to `Option.map`.